# How can I add my logo to real stuff in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Im a newbie here, Ive been learning how to design by myself and I want to learn more, so I hope you guys can understand.

My question is:

How can I add my logo to stuff like Mugs, T-Shirts and if possible, over Mountains (The texture is important on this one) and so on, using illustrator.

I dont want it be extremely obvious that it's not really there, so, Can you guys help me please?

Thank you very much

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I've tried copying my logo from illustrator to photoshop and then transform > warp. It doesnt really help as much as I'd like tho

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. if you are adding the logo to objects in photographs, then Photoshop is probably your best bet.  Look up tutorials if you don't know how to do it. There are some on Youtube [like this one](https://youtu.be/rnnlcB9v5-U?t=502) that uses a grid to set up a smart object.

Comment: Many logos contain mountains but a logo on a mountain is something different. I guess this is still only in software. Can you show an existing example of the wanted accuracy and richness of details? I guess it's not this https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1416/8662/products/el_cid_1961_british_quad_original_film_art_5000x.jpg?v=1569094072